# What is the "template method pattern" in cocoa with Object C ? ( Language comparison thinking )

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, virtual-functions, template-method-pattern

Here is [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) , Java and C++ can implement it easily with virtual function. How about Object C to implement this pattern ? Any example in cocoa touch (iOS) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [jer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551109/what-is-the-template-method-pattern-in-cocoa-with-object-c-language-compari/4551165#4551165) has already pointed out, all Objective-C methods are essentially virtual. It is a feature of the language which does not quite mesh with other C-like languages. That being said, the basics of the template method pattern can still be achieved in Objective-C, by "manually" forcing subclasses to implement certain functions. For example (using the convention in your linked Wikipedia article):

```
@interface Game
{
    int playersCount;
}
- (void)playOneGame:(int)numPlayers;
// "virtual" methods: 
- (void)initializeGame;
- (void)makePlay:(int)player;
- (BOOL)endOfGame;
- (void)printWinner;
@end

@implementation Game
- (void)initializeGame         { NSAssert(FALSE); }
- (void)makePlay:(int player)  { NSAssert(FALSE); }
- (BOOL)endOfGame              { NSAssert(FALSE); return 0; }
- (void)printWinner            { NSAssert(FALSE); }
- (void)playOneGame:(int)numPlayers
{
    //..
}
@end
```

The above code forces subclasses of `Game` to override the "virtual" methods by throwing an exception the moment one of the base class implementations is called. In effect, this moves the test from the compiler stage (as it would be in C++ or Java) and into the runtime stage (where similar things are often done in Objective-C).

If you *really* want to enforce the rule that subclasses are not allowed to override the `playOneGame:` method, you can attempt(*) to verify the correct implementation from within the `init` method:

```
@implementation Game
...
- (void)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }

    IMP my_imp = [Game instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(playOneGame:)];
    IMP imp = [[self class] instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(playOneGame:)];
    NSAssert(imp == my_imp);

    return self;
}
...
@end
```

(*) Note that this code does not result in a 100% rock-solid defense against subclasses which re-implement `playOneGame:`, since the very nature of Objective-C would allow the subclass to override `instanceMethodForSelector:` in order to produce the correct result.

Comment: Thanks ! Make sense to implement template method pattern with Object C. Straightforward to think that, any classic usage of this pattern in cocoa sdk ? I guess maybe no.

Comment: Hmm. Not that I know of, but that doesn't mean that it hasn't been done. The SDK often uses a combination of protocols and delegates, but that is not quite the same as the template method pattern.

Comment: There are lots of examples of template methods in Cocoa. UIView and NSView drawRect: and layoutSubviews e.g. They are called by setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C all methods are akin to C++ `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C Template Method Pattern is Used When you have a Skeleton of an Algorithm but it can be Implemented in different ways. Template method defines the steps to execute an algorithm and it can provide default implementation that might be common for all or some of the subclasses.

Let's take an example but First Look at the Picture

[image]

```
 @interface Worker : NSObject

- (void) doDailyRoutine;
- (void) doWork; // Abstract
- (void) comeBackHome; 
- (void) getsomeSleep;
@end

@implementation Worker

- (void) doDailyRoutine {
  [self doWork];
  [self comeBackHome];
  [self getsomeSleep];
  }

 - (void) doWork { [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]; }
 - (void) comeBackHome { [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]; }
 - (void) getsomeSleep { [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd]; }
 // [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd] it will force to call the subclass          Implementation
@end

@interface Plumber : Worker
@end

@implementation Plumber

- (void) doWork { NSLog(@“Plumber Work"); }

@end
@interface Electrician : Worker

@end

@implementation Electrician

- (void) doWork { NSLog(@“Electrician Work"); }

@end
@interface Cleaner : Worker

@end

@implementation Cleaner

- (void) doWork { NSLog(@“Cleaner Work"); }

@end
```

> In this example dowork() is an Abstract function which should be implemented by all the subclasses and this pattern is largely used in Cocoa Frameworks.

Hope it will help you to Understand the "Template Method Pattern".